# why is this UK firm's market capitalization number weird?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, stock-exchanges

https://uk.investing.com/equities/uk-comm-prop-trust

Hi, I am gathering UK stocks information through financial numbers. 
But as I was looking into this firm, I tried to calculate the market capitalization by myself, and I found shares outstanding * stock price isn't equal to the market capitalization of this stock which is 1.19B
I don't know how this number is 1.19B since the multiplication of shares outstanding and stock price isn't 1.19B

Thank you for your answer in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UK stocks are quoted in pence on the London Stock Exchange.  The market cap is quoted in pounds, so you need to divide by 100.

i.e. 92 * 1299412465 / 100 = 1.195B

Comment: Oh I couldn't think of pence unit!! thank you for your answer!:)